# How do I install Rake (Ruby on Rails)?

Tags: unix, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to install Ruby on Rails (I'm running a FreeBSD but don't want to use Ports for RoR) so this is a more generic unix/RoR question.

Simply what is the best way to install Rake.

http://rake.rubyforge.org/ suggests:

`% ruby install.rb`

or

`gem install --remote rake`

I have installed Ruby 1.9 and the path to its lib is

`/usr/local/lib/ruby/`

I'm not sure the best way of the two above options or if there any other recommendations. (Essentially, FreeBSD is still on Ruby 1.8 and so I just want to do all RoR in a self contained install, and not have the Ports gems mixed with other gems that are not in Ports).

Answer (score 1):

Ruby 1.9.2 (`lang/ruby19` port) ships with rake-0.8.7.

You may completely ignore Ruby 1.8 on FreeBSD, by a) deleting it and b) adding to `/etc/make.conf` the line:

```
RUBY_DEFAULT_VER=1.9
```

Then install `lang/ruby19` port, update rubygems (as root):

```
# gem update rdoc
# gem update --system
```

and finally, install rails:

```
# gem install rails
```

And forget about any gems from ports, use `gem` tool to manage gems.

If you want a non-system rails setup, install `shells/bash` port and manually install RVM https://rvm.beginrescueend.com/. It perfectly works in FreeBSD with bash as your shell.